# Three js - Multiple textures/images on single object

Tags: three.js, blender

I want to achieve following: export 1 object from blender -> apply 2 different textures to 2 different vertex groups (handles and body of the bag)

[image]

Function that loads model:

```js
      function loadModel() {
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var map = textureLoader.load('./leather.jpg');
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});

        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.load("bag.obj", function(object) {
          object.rotation.y = 90;
          scene.add(object);
          object.traverse( function ( node ) {
              if ( node.isMesh ) node.material = material;

            } );

          document.querySelector("h1").style.display = "none";
        });
      }
```

That will give this:
[image]

How to access different vertex groups and assign different textures to them? So handles can be out of wood, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender's Outliner, separate your vertex groups/meshes and rename them "bagHandle" and "bagBody" accordingly.

Following code should work.

```
function loadModel() {
  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var bagBodyMap = textureLoader.load('./leather.jpg');
  var bagBodyMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: bagBodyMap});
  var bagHandleMap = textureLoader.load('./wood.jpg');
  var bagHandleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: bagHandleMap});
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  loader.load("bag.obj", function(object) {
      object.rotation.y = 90;
      scene.add(object);
      object.traverse( function ( node ) {
          if ( node.isMesh ){
              if ( node.name == "bagHandle" ){
                  node.material = bagHandleMaterial;
              } else if ( node.name == "bagBody" ){
                  node.material = bagBodyMaterial;
              }
          }
      });
      document.querySelector("h1").style.display = "none";
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did, however, manage to think through of this myself and get the concept of it. The key thing is that one .obj can hold multiple meshes and you iterate through them via object.traverse, as you said. Helpful code however, thanks much!